# cycling Ranksum on Stata

Tags: stata

I have some data with two different groupd of patients automatically exported from a diagnostic tool.

Variables are automatically nominated by the diagnostic tool (e.g. `L1DensityWholeImage, L1WholeImageSHemi, L1WholeImageIHemi , L1WholeETDRS ,[...], DeepL2StartLayer, L2Startoffsetum, L2EndLayer, [...], Perimeter, AcircularityIndex` )

I have to perform a Rank-sum test (or Mann-Whitney *U* test) with all the variables (> of 80) by group.

Normally, I should write each single analysis like that:

`ranksum L1DensityWholeImage, by(Group)`

`ranksum L1WholeImageSHemi, by(Group)`

`ranksum L1WholeImageIHemi, by(Group)`

`ranksum L1WholeETDRS, by(Group)`

Is there any way or code to write the command with a *varlist*? And maybe to obtain only 1 output result with all the p value?

e.g.: `ranksum L1DensityWholeImage L1WholeImageSHemi L1WholeImageIHemi  L1WholeETDRS, DeepL2StartLayer L2Startoffsetum L2EndLayer Perimeter AcircularityIndex, by(Group)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short answer is write a loop and customise output.

Here is a token example which you can run.

```
sysuse auto, clear 

foreach v of var mpg price weight length displacement { 
    quietly ranksum `v', by(foreign) porder 
    scalar pval = 2*normprob(-abs(r(z)))
    di "`v'{col 14}" %05.3f pval " " %6.4e pval  "   " %05.3f r(porder) 
}
```

Output is

```
mpg          0.002  1.9e-03   0.271
price        0.298  3.0e-01   0.423
weight       0.000  3.8e-07   0.875
length       0.000  9.4e-07   0.862
displacement 0.000  1.1e-08   0.921
```

Notes:

1. If your variable names are longer, they will need more space.
2. Displaying *P*-values with fixed numbers of decimal places won't prepare you for the circumstance in which all displayed digits are zero. The code exemplifies two forms of output.
3. The probability that values for the first group exceed those for the second group is very helpful in interpretation. Further summary statistics could be added.
4. Naturally a presentable table needs more header lines, best given with `display`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! It is perfect!

Comment: Note that `normprob()` has been replaced by `normal()` in newer versions of Stata (7+).

Comment: `normprob()` still works in Stata 15. What you're referring is just a cosmetic renaming to make names more consistent.

Comment: Hi Nick Cox! Thanks for your help.I'm trying to modify your code but i have some issues. I have set my varlist and my group variable. I have also changed the "col" option to fit my varname. I would like to add the number of observation for each group ( r(N 1) - r(N 2)) and put over the results list some "titles" (e.g. P-Value, PValue2, Porder- Observ. group 1 - Observ. group 2). I am trying to study the "display" function but I cannot figure out a solution...may you please help me? Thanks Hi Nick Cox!Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GiuseppeD'AmicoRicci Please ask a new question cross-referencing this  question **OR** edit this  question here adding new material and leaving the original question untouched. Note  that `display` is a command, not a function.